# Kafka streams: topic partitions->consumer 1:1 mapping not happening

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have written a streams application to talk to topic on cluster of 5 brokers with 10 partitions. I have tried multiple combinations here like 10 application instances (on 10 different machines) with 1 stream thread each, 5 instances with 2 threads each. But for some reason, when I check in kafka manager, the 1:1 mapping between partition and stream thread is not happening. Some of the threads are picking up 2 partitions while some picking up none. Can you please help me with same?? All threads are part of same group and subscribed to only one topic.
The kafka streams version we are using is 0.11.0.2 and broker version is 0.10.0.2

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7144 -- I would recommend to upgrade to the latest versions.

> Note: you do not need to upgrade your brokers